# Pass value in php and use in js

Tags: php, jquery

i have a php file with this code:

```
  <?php
dateIndaysoff($_GET['date']);
function dateIndaysoff($mydate){
 if(!$mydate)return false;


                $host = "localhost";
                $user = "user";
                $pass = "pass";
                $databaseName = "db";
                $con = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$databaseName);
                if ($con->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                    }

                $query = "SELECT date FROM table WHERE date = '$mydate'";
                $result = $con->query($query);
                 if ($result->num_rows < 1) {$exists =  "FALSE";} else {$exists = "TRUE";}
                 return $exists;
            }                               
        ?>
```

Now in my .js file i use this

```
jQuery(".datepicker").change(function() {  
   var val = jQuery(this).datepicker().val();
   var finalval = jQuery.get("url-to-phpfile/daysoff.php",{date:val});
  if (finalval) {
```

but its like i always have true as result. php by its own works perfect. i am trying in jquery to call php and pass through url the value from datepicker and if result is true do something. I have tried the jquery  with a fixed value and its working like a charm. The mistake i do should be or inside php receiving the value with GET or in jquery receiving the result.

What do i do wrong?

Comment: what's the date format you are passing to `$_GET['date']`? How is it stored in the db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be wrong, but it seems like you're assuming finalval to be your response, but it will actually be your XHR call. Try this in your listener:

```
jQuery(".datepicker").change(function() {  
    var val = $(this).datepicker().val();       // or $(this).val(); ?
    $.get( "ajax/test.html?date=" + val, function( data ) {
        alert( "Result is: " + data );
    });
});
```

And, as  an aside, don't forget to [escape](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) your injections, or use PDO binding.

Comment: yes but i want all this to do on change condition of .datepicker as posted at first place

Comment: Ya, so put it all into your .change listener. I'll update it to show you.

Answer (score -1):

Updated solution.
In php file i use this:

```
<?php

$conversion = $_GET['date'];
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($conversion));
dateIndaysoff($newDate);
$hello = dateIndaysoff($newDate);
echo 'Result:'.$hello . '<br>';
echo 'Converted date:'.$newDate. '<br>';
echo 'Initial date:'.$conversion. '<br>';
function dateIndaysoff($mydate){
        if(!$mydate)return false;

        //Connection
        $host = "localhost";
        $user = "user";
        $pass = "pass";
        $databaseName = "db";
        $con = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$databaseName);
        if ($con->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }

        //Select data   
        $query = "SELECT date FROM table WHERE date = '$mydate'";
        $result = $con->query($query);
       // $db=JFactory::getDbo();
         if ($result->num_rows < 1) {$exists =  "FALSE";} else {$exists = "TRUE";}
         return $exists;
    }                               
?>
```

and in .js i use this:

```
jQuery(".datepicker").change(function() {
var val = jQuery(this).datepicker().val();
console.log(val);
jQuery.get("/daysoff.php",{date:val},function(dateIndaysoff){ // send back 0 or 1
      if (dateIndaysoff) {
       console.log("hide");
        jQuery('.chzn-drop li:nth-child(9)').hide();
        jQuery('.chzn-drop li:nth-child(10)').hide();
     } else {
       console.log("show");
         jQuery('.chzn-drop li:nth-child(9)').show();
         jQuery('.chzn-drop li:nth-child(10)').show();
     }
});
});
```

As you can see i have placed logs at php and js files in order to see whats going on. I get correct results if i use only php file with ?date at end of url and i see inside js that i get my date variable and it goes to URL.

But for some reason i get always HIDE condition from .js IF. I should get SHOW condition when date is equal to 30.04.2016 but it seems that either i have a mistake in js (possibly not) either i have something wrong between connection of those 2 files.

Any ideaS?

Comment: You're using an answer to ask a question? Anyway, it's easy to tell where your error is: console.log(dateIndaysoff);. You have a lot of problems with your PHP here, like quotes around true/false and echoing other stuff than your result. Did you try my answer above?